# java Calendar get hour before the next day

Tags: java, android, time, calendar, milliseconds

I have a date : 21/08/2013 17:05:06
And I would like to know the number of milliseconds before 22/08/2013 00:00:00

Is it possible to do that with Calendar object please ?
Thanks

**EDIT :**

My solution found :

```
Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault());
                cal2.setTimeInMillis(prevCalBatt.getTimeInMillis());
                cal2.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,1); //add a day
                cal2.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0); //set time to midnight
                cal2.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
                cal2.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
                cal2.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

                timeBetweenBoth+=(cal2.getTimeInMillis()-prevCalBatt.getTimeInMillis());
```

Comment: Have you read the Calendar javadoc? Are there any methods there that might help you?

Comment: I didn't see anything that would help me in the javadoc...

Answer (score 1):

Create one calendar object for each date, and then subtract their `getTimeInMillis()`.

Comment: Yes I thought about this solution but I would like to "automate" a generic solution because I have a lot of dates.
For each Calendar I can add one day but the time is always the same, so my calculation is always false.

Answer (score 0):

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");

GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();

cal.setTime(sdf.parse("22/08/2013 00:00:00"));

long millis = cal.getTimeInMillis();

cal.setTime(sdf.parse("21/08/2013 17:05:06"));

millis -= cal.getTimeInMillis();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the alarm by using this method:

```
/**
     * Set the Alarm
     *
     * @param context  the activity context
     * @param id       the alarm ID for this app
     * @param hour     the alarm hour
     * @param minute   the alarm minute
     * @param timeZone the timezone "am" = Calendar.AM or "pm" = Calendar.PM
     */
    public static void setAlarm(Context context, int id, int hour, int minute, String timeZone) {
        AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        AlarmStateCache cache = AlarmStateCache.getInstance(context);
        cache.saveState(State.ON);

        Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, to24Hour(hour, timeZone));
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

        if(calendar.before(now))
            calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,1);

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, YourReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, id, intent, 0);
        alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 1000 * 20, pIntent);
    }
```

And the Helper Method

```
   public static int to24Hour(int hour, String zone) {
        if (1 > hour && hour < 12)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Hour must only be 1 - 12!");

        return zone.equals("am") ? hour : hour + 12;
    }
```

In the `setAlarm` method we could see that we add 1 day if our current time is already passed away, therefore we can ensure that time will will prompt on the next day around.